# finding a neon instruction corresponding to sse instruction

Tags: arm, sse, simd, neon

I want to know what is the equivalent instruction/code to SSE instruction in Neon instruction.

```
__m128i a,b,c;
c = _mm_packs_epi32(a, b);
```

Packs the 8 signed 32-bit integers from a and b into signed 16-bit integers and saturates.

I checked the equivalent instruction on ARM site but I didn't find any equivalent instruction.
http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0204j/Bcfjicfj.html

Comment: Also see [`sse_to_neon.h`](https://github.com/dimitriv/Ziria/blob/master/csrc/neon/sse_to_neon.h) The header provides many of the common ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no instruction that directly does what you want, but all the building blocks to build one are there:

The saturation/narrow instruction is:

```
int16x4_t vqmovn_s32 (int32x4_t)
```

This intrinsic saturates from signed 32 bit to signed 16 bit integers, returning the four narrowed integers in a 64 bit wide variable.

Combining these into your _mm_packs_epi32 is easy: Just do it for a and b, and combine the results:

```
  int32x4_t a,b;
  int16x8_t c;

  c = vcombine_s16 (vqmovn_s32(a), vqmovn_s32(b));
```

You may have to swap the order of the vcombine_s16 arguments.

Comment: can you please tell me one more neon instruction equivalent to _mm_storel_epi64.

Comment: my solution is to use vget_lang( 64x2,1) to get lower 64 bit register, and then use vst1q to store. is it correct??

Answer (score 2):

This pack/saturate operation comes under the [MOV](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0204j/Bcfjicfj.html) instruction category in NEON:

`VQMOVN (Vector Saturating Move and Narrow) copies each element of the operand vector to the corresponding element of the destination vector. The result element is half the width of the operand element, and values are saturated to the result width.`

Comment: (psst, not sure if you flagged to migrate [this steaming pile of dung](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19615856/27-ips-lcd-monitor?noredirect=1), but I think [superuser may put out a hit on you for it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203172/migrated-question-not-marked-as-migrated-on-source-site))

Comment: can you please tell me, neon instruction equivalent to _mm_storel_epi64.

Comment: my solution is to use vget_lang( int64x2_t ,1) to get lower 64 bit register, and then use vst1q to store. is it correct??